# Python .encode() issues (Amazon API)

Tags: python, python-3.x, encode, amazon-mws

I'm trying to figure out how to access Amazon's MWS API, but having quite a bit of difficulty. After reading the documentation and gathering what I can from other people's examples, I feel like I'm on the right track.

My issue right now is how my URL is being returned. I'm getting `b''` wrapped around some of the parameters, which I believe is due to the two `.encode()`'s I added in this line:

```
 hmac_obj = hmac.new(key.encode(), sig_data.encode(), hashlib.sha256)
```

But without having those, I get these errors (depending on which argument I do not encode):

```
TypeError: key: expected bytes or bytearray, but got 'str'

TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing
```

Rest of the code:

```
import sys, os, base64, datetime, hashlib, hmac, urllib
from time import gmtime, strftime
from requests import request
import urllib.parse
import urllib.request
import dateutil.parser

def get_timestamp():
    time = strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ", gmtime())
    return dateutil.parser.parse(time)

def calc_signature(method, domain, URI, request_description, key):
    sig_data = method + '\n' + \
        domain.lower() + '\n' + \
        URI + '\n' + \
        request_description

    hmac_obj = hmac.new(key.encode(), sig_data.encode(), hashlib.sha256)
    digest = hmac_obj.digest()

    return urllib.parse.quote(base64.b64encode(digest), safe='-_+=/.~')

SECRET_KEY = 'XXXXXXXX'
AWS_ACCESS_KEY = 'XXXXXXXX'
SELLER_ID = 'XXXXXXXX'
MARKETPLACE_ID = 'XXXXXXXX'
MWS_AUTH_TOKEN = 'XXXXXXXXXXX'

Action = 'GetLowestPricedOffersForASIN'
SignatureMethod = 'HmacSHA256'
SignatureVersion = '2'
Timestamp = get_timestamp()
Version = '2011-10-01'
CreatedAfter = '2011-10-01T23:00:57Z'
URI = '/Products/2011-10-01'
domain = 'mws.amazonservices.com'
proto = 'https://'
method = 'POST'
ASIN = 'B004KZQVF4'
itemcondition = 'New'

payload = {
    'AWSAccessKeyId': AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
    'Action': Action,
    'SellerId': SELLER_ID,
    'MWSAuthToken': MWS_AUTH_TOKEN,
    'SignatureVersion': SignatureVersion,
    'Timestamp': '2016-01-08T05%3A32%3A48Z',
    'Version': Version,
    'SignatureMethod': SignatureMethod,
    'CreatedAfter': CreatedAfter,
    'MarketplaceId.Id.1': MARKETPLACE_ID,
    'ASIN': ASIN,
    'ItemCondition': itemcondition
}

request_description = '&'.join(['%s=%s' % (k, urllib.parse.quote(payload[k], safe='-_+=/.~').encode('utf-8')) for k in sorted(payload)])

sig = calc_signature(method, domain, URI, request_description, SECRET_KEY)

url = '%s%s?%s&Signature=%s' % \
    (proto+domain, URI, request_description, urllib.parse.quote(sig))

headers = {
    'Host': domain,
    'Content-Type': 'text/xml',
    'x-amazon-user-agent': 'python-requests/1.2.0 (Language=Python)'
}

response = request(method, url, headers=headers)

print(sig)
```

Output:

```
https://mws.amazonservices.com/Products/2011-10-01?ASIN=b'XXXXXXXX'&AWSAccessKeyId=b'AKIAJEHA562QWNAIEIKA'&Action=b'GetLowestPricedOffersForASIN'&CreatedAfter=b'2011-10-01T23%3A00%3A57Z'&ItemCondition=b'New'&MWSAuthToken=b'amzn.mws.fca4aee8-689d-74a2-5430-128d34f56873'&MarketplaceId.Id.1=b'ATVPDKIKX0DER'&SellerId=b'A1JHXNTHRB2151'&SignatureMethod=b'HmacSHA256'&SignatureVersion=b'2'&Timestamp=b'2016-01-08T05%253A32%253A48Z'&Version=b'2011-10-01'&Signature=RyTmx2azYUWJ9dKiu1upbkKzKO2NuDvw3yQDWsDP%2BI4%3D
```

Not quite sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind - was looking in the wrong place. Was the encoding in this line that was causing me issues:

```
request_description = '&'.join(['%s=%s' % (k, urllib.parse.quote(payload[k], safe='-_+=/.~').encode('utf-8')) for k in sorted(payload)])
```